# sum the values of a vector based on unsorted values of another vector in dataframe based on increasing and decreasing values in it

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a larger data set but this will also do to help me out. What I want to do is sum the values of `y` based on whether the values of `x` increases on decreases.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,8,7,7,6,6,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,1)
y <- c(NA,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30)

(data<-data.frame(x, y))
```

basically what I want is

```
sum(y[1:10],na.rm = TRUE)
```

where `x` is increased until second 9 value

```
sum(y[11:18],na.rm = TRUE)
```

where `x` is decreased until value 1, etc.

I tried it with a loop or with `diff()` function but it sums all the negative or all the positive differences.

Can you please help me?

Well the expected output is

```
x1[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
y1[NA,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
sum[y1]

x2[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
y2[30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
sum[y2]

x3[1,2,2]
y3[30,30,30]
sum[y3]

x4[2,1]
y4[30,30]
sum[y4]

x5[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y5[30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
sum[y5]

x6[9,8,8,7,7,6,6,5]
y6[30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
sum[y6]

x7[5,6,7,9,10,11,12]
x7[30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
sum[x7]

x8[21,1]
y8[30,30]
sum[y8]

But all of these automatically.
```

Comment: Hi Maria, welcome to SO. Can you show the expected output too?

Comment: Seem you want your partitions with overlaps?

Comment: In my solution, both `cummax` and `cummin` are from base R, not from additional packages. My R version is 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this user function `f` can help

```
f <- function(df) {
  grp <- c()
  repeat {
    v <- df$x
    d <- diff(v)
    s <- d[d != 0][1]
    l <- with(rle(ifelse(s > 0, cummax, cummin)(v) == v), lengths[1])
    grp <- c(grp, list(head(df, l)))
    df <- tail(df, -(l - 1))
    if (nrow(df) <= 1) break
  }
  grp
}
```

which partitions the data frame according to the monotone fractions (with overlaps), such that

```
> lapply(f(data),function(v) with(v,list(x = x, y = sum(y,na.rm = TRUE))))
[[1]]
[[1]]$x
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9

[[1]]$y
[1] 270


[[2]]
[[2]]$x
[1] 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

[[2]]$y
[1] 270


[[3]]
[[3]]$x
[1] 1 2 2

[[3]]$y
[1] 90


[[4]]
[[4]]$x
[1] 2 1

[[4]]$y
[1] 60


[[5]]
[[5]]$x
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[5]]$y
[1] 240


[[6]]
[[6]]$x
[1] 9 8 8 7 7 6 6 5

[[6]]$y
[1] 240


[[7]]
[[7]]$x
[1]  5  6  7  9 10 11 12

[[7]]$y
[1] 210


[[8]]
[[8]]$x
[1] 12  1

[[8]]$y
[1] 60
```

Answer (score 1):

The following uses a standard `cumsum` trick to get the cut points where the vector `x` changes monoticity. Then `tapply` `sum` to the vector `y`.

```
d <- c(TRUE, diff(data$x) >= 0)
f <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(d))))
tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13 
#270 240  60  30 210  30  30  30  30  30  30  30 180  30
```

Note that the result is a named vector, for an unnamed one run

```
unname(tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 270 240  60  30 210  30  30  30  30  30  30  30 180  30
```

---

Following a request in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007361/sum-the-values-of-a-vector-based-on-unsorted-values-of-another-vector-in-datafra/66007634?noredirect=1#comment116705380_66007634), here is a named result `res`.

```
res <- tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
g <- c("down", "up")[d + 1]
names(res) <- tapply(g, f, '[', 1)

res
#  up down   up down   up down   up down   up down   up down   up down 
# 270  240   60   30  210   30   30   30   30   30   30   30  180   30
```

Comment: Can we also know whether the sum of y is on condition where x increases or decreases?

Comment: @MariaProvelegiou Yes, it is. See the edit.

Comment: Well I have one more question where the stable values as …,9,9,... or …..,2,2,.... are counted in on the increased or on the increased values?  For example if I had                          x<- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,9,8,7,7,6,5,4,3,2,1) my variable increases until the last 10 and decreases from 10 to 1. This is what I want. The code you gave me counts the increased values until first 10 and for some reason counts decrease from the second 10 and after. Do you might know why is this happening?

Comment: @MariaProvelegiou They are counted on the increased. You can change that by setting the condition in the first code line, `diff(data$x) >= 0`.

Comment: Also when there is a decrease like x<-c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) I want the same too count the decrease until the last 1 not the first.

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Unfortunately cummax's package is not available for my version in R